# Reduce number of redirects in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I currently force `HTTP` to `HTTPS` and also drop `www` for my domain `ahtag.com`, but when you request the root it redirects to `ahtag.com/en/home`.

Here's the `.htaccess` rewrite rules that I'm using.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# strip www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

SetEnvIf HOST "ahtag\.com$" LIVE=1

# forbid non-GET on non-HTTPS
RewriteCond %{ENV:LIVE} 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{ENV:LIVE} 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# cakephp rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works fine, but I want to add some specific rules for the root domain. This will reduce redirects and improve response time for first time visitors.

How can I rewrite the following (including schema, host and path).

```
http://www.ahtag.com --> https://ahtag.com/en/home
http://ahtag.com --> https://ahtag.com/en/home
https://www.ahtag.com --> https://ahtag.com/en/home
https://ahtag.com --> https://ahtag.com/en/home
```

You get the idea. I just want to redirect on a special URL to the default home URL.

I've read the Apache manual for [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) but I don't feel confident enough to push changes to the production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this rule just below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(ahtag\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%1/en/home [L,R=301]

# strip www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

SetEnvIf HOST "ahtag\.com$" LIVE=1

# forbid non-GET on non-HTTPS
RewriteCond %{ENV:LIVE} 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{ENV:LIVE} 1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# cakephp rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```